# Ajax post to PHP not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi i got a problem im doing a ajax post to a php file but in the php file its empty

```
JS
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(marker, i) {
return function() {

     var rid = locations[i][4]; //get id to varible
     console.log(rid);
     $.ajax({
            url: uri+'/helper.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {'referens': rid},
            success: function(data){
                console.log(rid);
                window.location = uri+'/helper.php';
            },error: function(data){
                alert('error'); 
            }
        });
    }
}(marker, i));
```

and my helper.php

```
<?php 
$referens = $_POST['referens']; 
echo $referens;
echo 1;
?>
```

the output in helper.php is only 1 and not my referens post

what if i want to use it like this in same file with location.reload();

```
 success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                location.reload();
            },error: function(data){
                alert('error'); 
            }
        });
    }
}(marker, i));

</script>
<?php include_once('helper.php');
 var_dump($referens); ?>
```

and helper.php

```
<?php 
   $referens = $_REQUEST['referens']; 
   echo $referens;
   echo 1;

   ?>
```

Comment: And what `console.log(rid);` says?

Comment: remove window.location and see whate console log outputs

Comment: my console log says 91 as it should do

Comment: `window.location = uri+'/helper.php';` why are you doing this?

Comment: I think a *logic* issue lies around that part

Comment: actually I will make a location.reload(); and include helper.php to use the $referens in same file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comments on other answers and on your post, I would like to mention this:

```
console.log(rid);
window.location = uri+'/helper.php';
```

In your success callback `rid` is `91` as it should be as per your comments and that is absolutely correct because at the `php` file you are trying to access a `POST` var.

But when this line executes `window.location = uri+'/helper.php';` then location changes and it makes a `GET` request, so it fails.

To get this var at `PHP` end you should try with `$_REQUEST('referens')` and you have to send it with url like this:

```
window.location = uri+'/helper.php?referens=' + rid;
```

and at your php end:

```
<?php 
    $referens = $_REQUEST['referens']; // <---change here.
    echo $referens;
    echo 1;
?>
```

---

From the docs [`$_REQUEST()`]:

*An associative array that by default contains the contents of `$_GET, $_POST` and `$_COOKIE`.*

Comment: @Locos see `location.reload();` does not adds a data string to your url, instead you can use `window.location.href+"?referens="+rid;` you can try this.

Comment: that one i know and it works, im just trrying to get around the ugly url that ends like /referenser/?referens=91 i want to load it with just the referenser/ and include the 91 var from helper.php where im posting 91 to :P

Comment: All right then just `post` to the current url then or why don't you get the response and update the html.

Comment: i need to convert my var rid to a php string and reload the page to use it in my php if() on the same page without using /referens?referens=91

Comment: i solved the problem with coockies
    document.cookie = "ref=" + rid;
    location.reload();

    $referens = $_COOKIE['ref'];


but you made it clear to me that i needed to rethink so thanks JAI

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.

You are printing the wrong variable.

Change

```
success: function(data){
  console.log(rid);
  window.location = uri+'/helper.php';
}
```

To

```
success: function(data){
  console.log(data); // Here you are getting return in data not as rid
  window.location = uri+'/helper.php?rid='+rid; // See, pass rid here.
}
```

in helper.php

```
<?php 
$referens = $_REQUEST['referens']; 
echo $referens;
echo 1;
?>
```

Comment: Indeed. But how would the OP have seen the incorrect value then ? rid should be correct, no ?

Comment: Pupil when i i do console.log(data) i get 91 1 and thats right but when window.location takes me to helper.php it only says 1

Comment: If you are redirecting to helper.php, then it will not get the E_POST parameter.

Comment: Rather, you should pass the rid to helper.php and then get it using $_GET.